# How to get the contents of a file in a different directory in php

Tags: php, filesystems

So I have a file system that looks something like this:

```
-htdocs(parent folder)
  -html
    -footer.html
    -css
      -style.css
  -login
    -index.php
  -index.php
```

What I want to do is to get the contents of `footer.html` from `login/index.php`. I have looked around but I can't seem to find anything that will fix my issue.

I'm using XAMPP for the web server if that matters.

Comment: take a look at the realpath command https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php and __DIR__ e.g. `file_get_contents(realpath(__DIR__ . '../login/index.php'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`../html/footer.html`. To go to the htdocs folder, you use two dots and then move to html folder where your footer file is.